# bootstrap carousel images are stacked on top of each other regardless of screen width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a bootstrap carousel that automatically switches between images in a given sequence. Everything is working in regards to controls (i.e arrows for going back and forth between pics & slide position indicator), but the images are stacked on top of each other when I load the page. Can someone point out an issue in this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Appraisal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=VT323" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.3.2/css/mdb.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <h1 class="animated slideInLeft">text goes here</h1>
      <p>...</p>
      <h4 class="animated slideInRight">portfolio</h4>
    </header>

    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>

      <div class="carousel_inner">

        <div class="item active">
          <img src="./pics/space_1.jpg" alt="Space 1" class="img-responsive">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Appraisal 1</h3>
            <p></p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="./pics/space_2.jpg" alt="Space 2" class="img-responsive">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Appraisal 2</h3>
            <p></p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="./pics/space_3.jpg" alt="Space 2" class="img-responsive">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Appraisal 3</h3>
            <p></p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <a href="#myCarousel" class="carousel-control" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon-prev left"></span>
      </a>
      <a href="#myCarousel" class="carousel-control" data-slide="next">
        <span class="icon-next right"></span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="skills">

    </div>

    <div class="certs">


    </div>

    <footer>
      <p>developed by: jefferson steelflex</p>

    </footer>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.3.2/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a typo. Just change the class "carousel_inner" in the slides container div for "carousel-inner".